# PHP 5.0: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

I have installed **php 7.0.15**. and the project I am working on, has a php version of **5.0**. How can I run **php 5.0** in **php 7.0.15**.I have other project working on **php 7.0.15**. so I can't install **php 5.0**. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: You can't. In particular when you need mysql_* functions which were specifically removed from PHP 7.

Comment: _"How can I run php 5.0 in php 7.0.15"_ .. ehm, you can't since they are two totally different versions?

Comment: `mysql_*` was removed on PHP 7.0. The closest you can do to solve it is to use `mysqli_*`. Or write your own `mysql_* layer`.

Comment: I have huge amount of `mysql_*` queries. so is there any extension or something like that?

Comment: Quoting myself: [...]`write your own mysql_* layer.`. That means: rewrite the `mysql_*` functions to use `mysqli_*`.

Comment: thank you for your comment but i have shortage of time. so is there any other way?

Comment: @Fred-ii- After some thinking, I still can't see how that is a duplicate of this one. The question there is "Why shouldn't I use `mysql_*`?", while this is closer to "Oh no! I have PHP 7.0, which doesn't have `mysql_`, but this huge code was made with it in mind. What can I do now?". Both are very related, but ask distinct things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try: You can re-write the functions using `mysqli_*`.

This is just a starting point!

```
<?php
    if(!function_exists('mysql_connect') && function_exists('mysqli_connect'))
    {
        $_GLOBALS["\0MYSQL"] = array();

        function mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password)
        {
            $_GLOBALS["\0MYSQL"][] = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        }

        function mysql_select_db($database_name)
        {
            return mysqli_select_db(end($_GLOBALS["\0MYSQL"]), $database_name);
        }

        [...]
    }
```

This is just a proof-of-concept and is meant to exemplify what I mean.
I'm not sure if someone already wrote this, and my Google-fu is terrible.

Also, don't forget to define all the constants that you use from `mysql_*`.

Hope this helps.